# How to Extract the words containing a specific combination of letters from a long string in spotfire?

Tags: python, r, spotfire

For example from the below string,

```
abc6:ContextData abc6:xyz1 iCare abc6:xyz2 abc6:xyz3  abc6:xyz4 <abc6:xyz5  abc6:xyz6  abc6:xyz7 abc6:ContextData
```

I want to extract the words preceded by "`abc6`." For "`abc6:xyz3`" I want the suffix `xyz3`. For the longer example, the output would be like:

```
ContextData,xyz1,xyz2,xyz3,xyz4,xyz5,xyz6,xyz7,ContextData
```

do we need any regular expression for these?

Comment: how do you extract `xyz1` from `iCare`?? What is the working principle?

Comment: sorry question was incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An R-base Solution based on `substr` function is:

```
z  <- "abc6:ContextData abc6:xyz1 iCare abc6:xyz2 abc6:xyz3 abc6:xyz4 <abc6:xyz5 abc6:xyz6 abc6:xyz7 abc6:ContextData"
z1 <- unlist(strsplit(z, split=" "))
z2 <- z1[substr(z1, start=1, stop=5)=="abc6:"]
z3 <- substr(z2, start=6, stop=nchar(z2))
cat(z3, sep=",")
```

Result:

```
ContextData,xyz1,xyz2,xyz3,xyz4,xyz6,xyz7,ContextData
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post is tagged with both the languages `r` and `python`

In `r`, you can use `gsub()` to replace the pattern "`abc6:`" by the empty string.

In python, you can implement `gsub` as follows:

```py
import re

def gsub(old, new, search_space):
    return re.sub(old, new, search_space)
```

Replacing `abc6:` with the empty string:

```py
z = "abc6:ContextData abc6:xyz1 iCare abc6:xyz2 abc6:xyz3 abc6:xyz4"
z2 = gsub("abc6:","",z)
> z2
[1] "ContextData xyz1 iCare xyz2 xyz3 xyz4"
```

If you want commas instead of spaces, you can then use

```py
z3 = gsub(" ",",",z2)
> z3
[1] "ContextData,xyz1,iCare,xyz2,xyz3,xyz4"
```

Or if you are looking for a vector,

```py
> strsplit(z2," ")[[1]]
[1] "ContextData" "xyz1"        "iCare"       "xyz2"        "xyz3"        "xyz4"
```

Comment: Getting rid of the prefix `abc6:` preserves words which don't have that prefix, such as `iCare`. I think we want to extract all suffixes of strings beginning with `abc6:`